# php SQL DATABASE

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a create database and have about 8 tables in Database also created Primary keys and foreign-keys in appropriate tables. But when I insert data in primary-table, my other table doesn't show updated data.

I mean, say I have a table which has data  for names like ;
N is (name)
N1 = George, N2 = Ross, N3 = Rim ...etc now that means i have Primary key N1,N2,N3 etc..

Now, when I insert this primary keys in others table it should shows me name like George, ross and rim instead of primary-key number it self(N1,N2,N3).

How can I get names instead PK itself?

Comment: So you need to cross references two tables? you can join two tables together and then that way you get all the information you need, but need a little more info about your design than what you have there. I'm assuming you're using MySQL?

Comment: I think before using a database it would be wise to read up about relational databases and normalisation to learn the theory.

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding the concept of keys in relational databases. Keys are there, not to copy data from similar tables but to show the relations between data in different tables. They help to understand how the data between different tables is related - that is where the name "relational database" comes from. They also speed up querying of that data if indexed.

You can read more about the usage of keys here: [Keys and normalization](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/relations-keys-normalization-sql-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

I am still unclear on what exactly you want to do with the database. but let me demonstrate you on the basic of database and how you should be using it. Consider a table `users` where you will be storing the data related to user.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

the column `id` holds the primary key and have an attribute called auto_increment, now what this means is every time you insert a record to this table the `id` attribute gets incremented and you don't have to worry about inserting any value in this column because your database will take care of that. for example take a look at insert query below.

```
INSERT INTO users(name,email,phone) VALUES('First Name', 'first@domain.com', '9999999999');
INSERT INTO users(name,email,phone) VALUES('Second Name', 'second@domain.com', '8888888888');
INSERT INTO users(name,email,phone) VALUES('Third Name', 'third@domain.com', '2222222222');
INSERT INTO users(name,email,phone) VALUES('Fourth Name', 'fourth@domain.com', '3333333333');
```

did you see you did not insert any `id` here. this is because it is database who will handle the logic. now the first record will hold the value `1` the second will have `2` the third one `3` and the fourth one `4` and so on.

hope this helps you.